# Application settings Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm developing for WP8 and I need to store custom app settings. I found func 'ApplicationData' but it's not supported in WP8. Can you help me? I want to store permanent variables provided by user. For  example:

```
Country = UA
News = 1
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Isolated Storage or ApplicationData.LocalSettings like this :

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

// Create a simple setting

localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";

// Read data from a simple setting

Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

if (value == null)
{
    // No data
}
else
{
   // Access data in value
}

   // Delete a simple setting

localSettings.Values.Remove("exampleSetting");
```

Check this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings) and also this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx)